# Storyboard: Set UITableViewCell autolayout constraints for dynamic content

Tags: ios, storyboard, autolayout

I'm making a view to display news content, i have various cells that should adjust it's size to the content.

```
newsFeedTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

So when populating the cells i set the ImageView to the size of the Image i get from my API, then the TextView should scale to the "remaining width" of the cell.
[image]

When i set these constraints i get error:
[image]

[image]

How should i set my constraints? If i set a width constraint on my ImageView it wont adjust when i change the frame size in code.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for storyboard to know what's width of these elements and hence the error.

Since there's no way for you to know width in advance, what you can do is assign any width and heigth constraint to imageView. Then, make outlets of that constraints(you can drag and drop them constraint outlets just like any other element) in you custom cell. Set the width and height constraint according to data you receive.

eg

```
imageViewWidthConstraint.constant = recievedObject.imageSize.width
imageViewHeightConstraint.constant = recievedObject.imageSize.height
```

You may also need to call

```
setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
```